# modprobe unknown symbol using existing kernel module

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, dependencies, kernel

I'm writing a kernel module which uses an existing function (nf_conntrack_in()) from a netfilter kernel module (nf_conntrack) and am having dependency issues.

My module compiles fine, i'm using the Module.symvers from the kernel build so kbuild is aware of the symbol during compilation.

I used depmod -a to ensure that modprobe is aware of the dependancy (my module is called proxy):

line in modules.dep:

> misc/proxy.ko: kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.ko

I know the symbol is in the kernel because it is in /proc/kallsyms:

> ffffffffa06465b0 t nf_conntrack_in [nf_conntrack]

Evrythings seems good to go but when I modprobe my module i ge the following error:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'proxy': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter

and the kernel log states:

> proxy: Unknown symbol nf_conntrack_in

Anyone have any suggestion on how to debug/resolve this further?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any warning about unknown symbol during building the module? According to sources, the symbol `nf_conntrack_in` is exported only for "GPL"-licenced modules; which license your module has?

Comment: I actually came across the same discovery last night, added the line:

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL")

to my module and can now insert it with no errors.